# how to find principal components and orientation of a point cloud using point cloud library

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have a point cloud of a wooden block. I have found the centroid of that  point cloud. Now I am trying to find the Principal components and orientation using point cloud library. Below is the code I have tried. Correct me if you havent understood something.

```
        Eigen::Vector4f centroid;
        Eigen::Matrix3f covariance_matrix;

        // Extract the eigenvalues and eigenvectors
        Eigen::Vector3f eigen_values;
        Eigen::Matrix3f eigen_vectors;

        pcl::compute3DCentroid(*cloud_filtered,cluster_indices,centroid);

        // Compute the 3x3 covariance matrix
        pcl::computeCovarianceMatrix (*cloud_filtered, centroid, covariance_matrix);
        pcl::eigen33 (covariance_matrix, eigen_vectors, eigen_values);
        std::cout << "centroid-x:"<<centroid[0]<<"centroid-y:"<<centroid[1]<<"centroid-z:"<<centroid[2]<<std::endl;
```

Comment: It looks fine. Is there a problem?

Comment: I want to find the orientation of the point cloud in the cluster_indices.

Comment: The eigenvector corresponding to the greatest eigenvalue should be approximately the direction of maximum volume distribution of the object, which I assume is what you want. Is there some other form in which you wanted to express this orientation?

Comment: Yes, I wanna find the transformation matrix of Principal components with respect to world coordinate.

Comment: The three eigenvectors you want should be independent and you just need them to be orthonormal for them to make up a rotation matrix (IIRC) so I would recommend taking the first eigenvector as-is, subtracting from the 2nd eigenvector the projection of the 2nd eigenvector onto the 1st, and then subtracting from the 3rd eigenvector its projection onto the plane formed by the 1st and 2nd eigenvector. I believe that should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a rotation matrix representing an orientation, we can choose the axis in which the volume distribution of the object is highest (normalised first eigenvector - that is the eigenvector associated with the largest eigenvalue) as the first column of the matrix.

For the 2nd column of the matrix choose the 2nd eigenvector but you have to subtract from it its projection onto the 1st eigenvector so that it is orthogonal to the first. To calculate its projection you can use the dot product - if the eigenvectors are already normalised you can just use the dot product to calculate the length of the vector to subtract: so dot product the two vectors and multiply the 1st vector by the dot product, then subtract the resulting vector from the 1st eigenvector.

For the 3rd column there will only be one choice left - the cross product of the two calculated above.

Comment: Is there a way to represent eigenvectors as axis?.

Comment: As I have written in the answer, by processing them so that they become orthonormal they can be used as axes of a coordinate system. Please feel free to ask more questions but maybe more detail is required if I have missed your point again.

Comment: Note that the columns of a rotation matrix are in fact the axes of the rotated coordinate system.

Comment: Thank you. Can you refer this link and tell me if you have any suggestions. http://stackoverflow.com/q/28844865/2981361

Comment: For that question I recommend you study the API for PCLVisualizer.